# need to call 2 different functions on one onDateChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm doing a register page on react native, and I have this date picker that works perfectly fine, but the problem is that I need it to call 2 different methods when the date is changed, but it does only one, I put a console.log as if it was the other function that I'm going to call, but when I put the console.log the datepicker doesn't display the date in the form, when I remove the console.log it does it perfectly, what am I doing wrong?

this is the date picker I'm using
https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker#readme

this is my code

```
    import React, {  useContext,useState} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';


import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';
const PersonalForm = ({onSubmit, errorMessage}) => {
 const [vBirthDate, setvBirthDate] = useState('');
    return ( 
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <View style={styles.containerdate}>
                <DatePicker 
                  date={vBirthDate} //initial date from state
                  mode="date" //The enum of date, datetime and time
                  placeholder="select date"
                  format="DD/MM/YYYY"
                  minDate="01/01/1900"
                  maxDate="01/01/2019"
                  confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                  cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                  androidMode="spinner"
                  customStyles={{
                    placeholderText: {
                      fontSize: 16,
                    },
                    dateIcon: {
                      height: 0,
                      width: 0,
                    },
                    dateText: {
                      color: '#b3b4b5',
                      fontSize: 16,
                    },
                    dateInput: {
                      borderWidth: 0,
                    }
                  }}
                  onDateChange={(date) => setvBirthDate(date),console.log('algo')} 
                />
              </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};



export default PersonalForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function body (with `{}` brackets), and call the methods that way.

```
onDateChange={(date) => {
    setvBirthDate(date);
    console.log('algo');
}}
```

I would recommend making it a separate function altogether though, for clarity and re-usability.

```
const myDateFunction = (date) => {
    setvBirthDate(date);
    console.log('algo');
}

onDateChange={(date) => myDateFunction}
```

In fact, the documentation you linked shows a very similar example to my first one, except you seem to have removed the brackets when it was implemented.

```
onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date})}}
```